# Where is the third antenna on this avalanche beacon PCB?

Tags: pcb, antenna, fcc

I have been looking at the pictures of the internal circuitry of a [Barryvox S avalanche beacon on the FCC ID website.](https://fccid.io/ARN-BARRYVOX-S/Internal-Photos/int-photos-3660153) I cannot open mine, since that would void the warranty.

This beacon, as all modern ones, features three antennas aligned with the three axes with the goal of improving signal detection.

Two of the antennas are very easy to spot
. See, for instance, the very last picture. I cannot find the third antenna, though.

Is it the metal, C-shaped rod that it is visible in the same picture? Wouldn't that make for a lousy antenna?

Avalanche beacons operate at 457 kHz, I expect a "serious" antenna for such a low frequency.

Comment: I even wondered if I should reply to this. Spam for what? I have to discuss beacon antennas in avalanche classes, and I just wondered where these antennas are... (given the low frequency, they have to be big, but I could only find 2 "big" antennas)

Comment: Then embed the pictures in your post.

Comment: Not sure if I am legally allowed to do so --- and the website is the FCC's website, not a vendor or manufacturer one...

Comment: If it's FCC it's probably public domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The third antenna is this spool choke.

Too short for an answer apparently